# How to find and extract a substring from a command output?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Before I go into details I'd like to stress the fact that using PowerShell is not an option, because the script is supposed to be run on machine where PowerShell might not be available.

I need to check for a version of Internet Explorer installed on a Windows machine and act upon it depending on which version it is.

So far my batch script looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ( 'reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v Version' ) do ( set IEVerReg=%%a )
endlocal
```

As you can see I am assigning `reg query` output to IEVarReg variable. The ouput is different on different Windows versions, examples:

Windows XP:

```
! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    Version     REG_SZ  8.0.6001.18702
```

Windows 7:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    Version    REG_SZ    9.0.8112.16421
```

Ideally, I'd like to get the first digit from the version number and do something like:

```
if
  version == 8
then
  execute this
elseif
  version == 9
then
  execute that
```

I'm sure I'll figure out how to do the `if` part once I get the version number, but it's the getting version number part I cannot figure out. I could do it easily in bash, perl, etc. but have no idea about Windows Command Line.

Help would be hugely appreciated.

PS. I'v seen [Jerold Schulman's script](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/internet/jsi-tip-8332-how-can-i-use-the-command-line-to-determine-the-version-of-internet-explorer-that-is-installed-) but it returns the whole version number which is too much for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to put together all of this pieces

1. access the registry to query the version number. See `REG QUERY /?`

   ```
   REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v Version
   ```
2. extract the line that contains the version from the information returned by the `REG` command. You do this piping the output of `REG` into the `FIND` command. See `HELP FIND`

   ```
   REG ... | FIND "REG_SZ"
   ```
3. set the result into a variable. You do it with the `FOR /F` command. Use `tokens=3` to extract the version number that is in the third position of the returned line. Also note the caret `^` that is needed to escape the pipe character `|`. See `HELP FOR`

   ```
   FOR /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v Version ^| FIND "REG_SZ"') DO (
     SET v=%%a
   )
   ```
4. extract the major version number from the version string. Use `delims=.` to parse at the period. See `HELP FOR`. For the appropriate expansion of the variables, you must use the extended expansion and use the `!` syntax to access the variables. Also, use `/A` to treat it as a number. See `HELP SET`

   ```
   FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%m in ('echo !v!') do (
     SET /A m=%%m
   )
   ```
5. finally, add your logic for the IE version

   ```
   IF .!m!==.8 (
     echo it's 8
   ) ELSE (
     ...
   ```

The first version of the working BAT must be something like this...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v Version ^| FIND "REG_SZ"') DO (    
    set v=%%a 
    echo !v!
    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%m in ('echo !v!') do (
      SET /A m=%%m
    )
    IF !m! EQU 8 (
      echo it's 8
    ) ELSE (
      IF !m! EQU 9 (
        echo it's 9
      ) ELSE (
       echo norrrrr
      )
    )
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 3):

Back in the old days, before I stopped using Microsoft products entirely, I swore by a product called 4DOS from [JP Software](http://jpsoft.com/).  The company still exists, and they have kept their product line up to date.  It's commercial software, but it made DOS+Windows+OS/2 scripting a breeze.  (And yes, REXX is not a breeze.)

4DOS was also licensed by Norton and released as NDOS, which got a bit more press than the original version.

That said, if memory serves, you should also be able to use the SET command to create a variable substring.

```
SET start=1
SET length=1
SET string=%IEVerReg%
CALL SET substribg=%%string:~%start%,%length%%%
```

I'd love to know if this works.  I don't have a Windows box around to test it on, fortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight modification of what you linked to that seems to work:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set qry=reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v Version
set fnd=findstr /I /L /C:"REG_SZ"
for /f "Tokens=2*" %%u in ('%qry%^|%fnd%') do (
 set vsn=%%v
)
@echo %vsn:~0,1%
endlocal
```